# Increase navbar text input length

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The default "search box" in the navbar is:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I'm trying to increase the length of the `input` horizontally so I can see and type more text.

How can I increase the length of the text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this class to the current css class of the input text box

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control span10" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I add span10, you can add span4, span5, span6 ...... depends on the length you want

Comment: add span1 to span12 depends on the width you want

Answer (score 0):

You can change the CSS attribute `width` or use the HTML attribute `size`.

CSS example: should make the elements with the `search-class-here` class 400px wide

```
.search-class-here { width: 400px; }
```

HTML example: should make the textbox around 40 characters in width.

```
<input type="text" size="40">
```